# Including a link to a SharePoint list item in an email

Tags: list, workflow, lookup-column, id

I have two lists. In one list a user enters system details which then kicks off a Workflow which then sends an email to an approver. The email has a link to the second list where the approver ticks on some check boxes. What I'd like to do is to include a link to the item in the first list.

What's the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your workflow is running on first list you can easily build the URL to display form of current item and use it in email. Follow the steps:

1. Create a new workflow variable.
2. Use the action `Set Workflow Variable`, select the newly create variable and now click on `...` to open string builder.
3. In string builder put the URL to list item `display form`, append `?Id=` string to it.
4. Now, from the lower left corner click on `Add or Change Lookup`.
5. In this, select Current Item and ID and insert it.

It will look like following:

[image]

That's it. Use the same workflow variable in Send email body to create hyperlink. I am using relative URL in this example but you need to put absolute URL to display form, so that email will point to right URL.

Comment: Cheers, any idea how I'd do it with Nintex?

Comment: i never worked on nintex workflow, but they do have the same concepts. Use this document http://help.nintex.com/en-US/nintex2013/help/Workflow/RootCategory/Actions/Nintex.Workflow.SetVariable.htm

Comment: glad it worked.